# How to design table with many columns in sort key?

Tags: amazon-redshift

I am prototyping redshift and need some advice on sort key design.  I have a table with 5 numeric values and 20 columns that can we used for filtering.  I am using the date as the dist key, but I am lost for the sort key design.

I have weights on the sort columns based on historical usage, but how do I handle this in redshift.  Creating a sortkey (col1, col2,.. col20) doesn't seem to be the best way to do this.  Do I create a sort key using the top 5 most used filters?  Or some other method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a lot of options, not easy at all :) Based on a feeling and how you describe the table , I think you should use a INTERLEAVED SORTKEY  and add up to 8 columns. If the columns are not spread, so for example 2 columns are dates that are growing in the same time, like start , end , or id's that are growing in sync , this is not a good solution. If the data is evenly distributed on the 8 columns then this is a really good SORTKEY option.

You need to do a lot of testing, there are a lot of options , do you have only this table or other tables too ?

Another question is what type of DISTSTYLE will you use ? Is the table small , big ? You have multiple options , depends on the amount of free space on every node and other factors. Try all of them one by one if you have enough space.

See here : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/viewing-distribution-styles.html

More info could help me guide you better. Check this link : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/tutorial-tuning-tables.html

GL !

Answer (score 0):

Using a date as a `DISTKEY` is quite unusual.

The general rule is:

- Set the `DISTKEY` to a column that is frequently used in a `JOIN` statement. This ensures that data in both tables are co-located on the same slice, so they can JOIN without having to transfer data between slices.
- Set the `SORTKEY` to a column that is most frequently used in a `WHERE` statement. This makes it easier to "jump over" disk blocks that *do not* contain relevant data because each block is marked with a min and max value for the column.

In general, avoid using Interleaved Sort because it requires too much overhead when running a `VACUUM`. Just sort on the field most commonly used in a `WHERE`, which is frequently the Date column.

See: [Amazon Redshift Best Practices for Designing Tables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_designing-tables-best-practices.html)